# Mongo DB : Is it possible to know how many Database calls are made to the Mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb

This is my java class that will connect to Mongo DB and fetch the Data .

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        DBCursor cursor  = null;
        DBCollection coll = null;
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        String symbol = args[0];
        query.put("symbol", "" + symbol);
        cursor  = coll.find(query);
        int count = coll.find(query).count();
    }
}
```

My question is , is it possible to know how many queries are made to the Mongo DB through this program ??

What i want to know is that whether two calls are made to the Mongo DB with this below statements

```
  cursor  = coll.find(query);

 int count = coll.find(query).count();
```

Is it possible to know if two calls are amde to the Mongo DB with the above ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MongoDB *profiling* to see the queries that are executed against the server. See the MongoDB documentation for further information: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/

In short words: Execute `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` in your shell and look into the `system.profile` collection on your server.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the only program connecting to MongoDB you can turn on profiling: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

You would turn profiling upto its max level (2), however if this is just one application of many then there might be (as in PHP) a MongoLog class ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongolog.php ) you could use.